# Using ASP.NET Web API controller needs authorization, as the Data Source of SSRS Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm having the application witch collecting data via REST calls and planning to generate reports of it using the SQL server reporting service. I'm having a problem with setting up web API controller which needs authorization, as end point URL in SQL server report builder connection string. How may I pass authorization token from report builder end to the application for generate XML ???

I'm perfectly getting data and able to generate report when I commented the [Authorize] in web API controller.